# How to find the duration when 100 users login to a web application and clicking on a filter at the same time in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have a web page which contains many filters and some as drop-down options. For example, Filter called (Time Range-- with options Last 24 hours, All, Last 7 Days).

The web page supposes to open by 100 users at the same time and select one option from the Time Range drop-down).

Kindly let me know how to find the duration by 100 users at the same time and select one option from the Time Range drop-down).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter automatically measures response time for each sampler, if you want to have the total time - open .jtl results file using [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/) or [Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en/excel) or equivalent and sum up all the response times for all 100 samplers

In order to guarantee the desired concurrency add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of the request and set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to `100`

Answer (score 0):

Add **View results table Listener** to the suite to check the duration and Start time of each thread and connect time of each thread.

As I understood  you  want to check the load of 100 concurrent users clicking the filter , so the login process and its load should not interfere the load testing of users clicking the filter button. Hence, As mentioned in above comment, you can use  **Synchronizing Timer** as child f the requests. What it does is, it is synchronized with the login requests  and wait for the response of all the 100 users getting logged in. Once all the 100 users are logged in, Synchronizing Timer play its role by sending (clicking) requests at the same time same second. Cant ensure same milliseconds. There might be small difference in milliseconds, which you can see in View results table (**start time**).